# Php memory limit issue while scraping huge file

Tags: php, xml, apache, memory-limit

I'm scraping this huge xml file (300k lines ~ 11MB) with Simple Html Dom and having some issues with memory limits. So I added some php.ini comands to override default settings and enable full control of memory. Bad idea.

My code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '-1');
$xml = file_get_contents('HugeFile.xml'); 
$xml2 = new simple_html_dom();
$xml2->load($xml);

foreach($xml2->find('tag1') as $element) {
        $element->innertext = str_replace('text to replace','new text',$element>innertext);

    }

$html->save('output'.xml');    
}
```

Now, Is there a way to make this script work smoothly in a reasonable time without any memory issue?
This can be done easily with a text editor, but I need to automate it as I have plenty of files to edit.

Comment: Well, either get a bigger package (with higher memory limits) or split the files into smaller pieces. Reading it chunk by chunk will presumably not help as you need the DOM to be ready when iterating over the fields.

Comment: Isn't there any php function that can free the used memory inside the loop for a given number of iterations?

Comment: If you are running PHP FPM -- some ini_set calls are ignored.

Comment: Use a Pull Parser like [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php)?

Comment: If possible, I would recommend to use an external XML parser, you won't need to increase PHP's memory limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better way to do it: No need for the DOM here, I just `str_replace` stuff inside the string returned by `file_get_contents` then put it in another file with `file_put_contents`. Simple and neat:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('HugeFile.xml'); 
$new = str_replace('text to replace','new text',$xml);
file_put_contents('output.xml');
```

And `preg_replace` may come in handy for complex modifications.